# Creating a Decorator for angular 2+ that returns the last result of a service http call

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I have a component calling a service like this

```
  this.service.GetCountries()
  .subscribe((pCountries: ICountry[]) => {
    this.mCountries = pCountries;
  });`
```

my service looks something like this

```
private countriesCache$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

GetCountries(pForceRefresh?: boolean) {

   if (!this.countriesCache$.observers.length || pForceRefresh) {
     this.http.get<ICountry[]>(path + 'GetCountries')
       .subscribe(
         countries => {
           this.countriesCache$.next(countries)
         },
         error => {
           this.countriesCache$.error(error);
           // Recreate the Observable as after Error we cannot emit data anymore
           this.countriesCache$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
         }
       );
   }

   return this.countriesCache$;
}
```

As you can see I am caching the result and returning the cached data to every subsequent request.

Is there a way I can move this caching logic into a Decorator ? I cant seem to find any examples of this online other than this [package](https://github.com/angelnikolov/ngx-cacheable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a *npm package* that I've never try, but I've heard about.

Check the github : https://github.com/angelnikolov/ngx-cacheable

install it with : `npm install ngx-cacheable`